# Directive syntax error on enter/return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, syntax-error

**noob alert**

This is weird - trying to create a custom directive in AngularJS, when I write this code:

```
myModule.directive('myTab', function(){
    console.log('--Inside TAB directive--');
    return 
    {
        template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
    };
});
```

It throws the exception:
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined*

However, this code runs fine:

```
myModule.directive('myTab', function(){
    console.log('--Inside TAB directive--');
    return {
        template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
    };
});
```

The only difference is the opening curly brace is on the next line in the first code. Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: Looks from the error that something else is causing the error.

Comment: @OmriAharon I am able to reproduce it consistently - if I move the curly brace after "return" to the next line it throws the error, else its fine.

Comment: Short answer is: auto-semicolons. Long answer is: don't put opening brace on the next line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are returning from the function and the next line is ignored. It will literally just see return, and return `undefined`